# UserManager unable to find user by id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Im trying to delete a user from the system, Im first trying to check weather the user exsists so I can remove them from the roles along with deleting thier accounts but when I go to assign the user about to be deleted using the userManager it throws an error.

```
 private static ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    private UserManager<ApplicationUser> uManager = 
            new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db));
    private RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager =
              new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(db));
```

Then the delete Action result code is as follows

```
 public ActionResult Delete(int id)
   {
       ApplicationUser user = uManager.FindById(id);
       try
       {
           if (user != null)
           {
               IdentityResult identityResult = uManager.Delete(user);
               TempData["message"] = "User Deleted.";
           }
           else
           {
               TempData["message"] = "User not found.";
           }
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           TempData["message"] = "Exception deleting user '"
               + user.UserName + "' - " + ex.InnerException.Message;
       }
       return RedirectToAction("Index");
   }
```

The error that appears when I use the uManager is as follows and am unsure of why it is not working:

> cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why is your DbContext static?  Also, what does FindById return?  Is it generic?  Are there different subclasses of user?

Comment: Not sure why its static it just produces an error without it, and findById should find and select the person that is to be deleted in the system. I havent finished the rest of the actionresult but It will remove the user from all groups then delete them. To find the groups they are in my idea was to find and save the to be deleted user to a user object then search and remove their groups then delete that user.

Comment: How is your UserId-field defined? As a standard ASP.NET identity defines the username as string. In this case you should say `uManager.FindbyId(id.ToString())`.

Comment: Thanks that worked, If you want to put that as an answer I could mark it as solved.